# Local hostnames not resolved after a VPN connection is established

Tags: openvpn, resolv.conf

The context:

I have a raspberry pi headless torrent box.
It downloads torrents to a local SMB share which is mounted with autofs.
As I download torrents I also use a VPN. It is set up with OpenVPN and it updates the resolv.conf file with the VPN's DNS servers after (dis)conneting.
After this, I can't resolve any local hostnames, and thus autofs can't mount the share.

Is there a way to keep the resolution of the local hostnames?

Comment: This can be normal behaviour for a full tunnel VPN.

Comment: Have you got lines in your OpenVPN client configuration file that look like this, `up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`? If so, comment them out.

Comment: I would add whatever hostnames I need to /etc/hosts with the local IP address and leave the openvpn config as-is.